# combining crossfit with stronglifts - both scheduling and weight intensity

Tags: strength-training, stronglifts, crossfit

I am in okay shape, so I decided to join a crossfit box. I have been doing crossfit for about months now, and I really enjoy it. However, I find that I am having trouble doing some of the more strength-intensive movements like pullups and toes-to-bar, etc. So I figured I should start a strength program. Stronglifts seems like a good fit since I am rather new to strength training. I have been doing Stronglifts for about 2 weeks.

I am trying to figure out how best to balance out my schedule to include both of these programs. There are 2 questions here: scheduling and weight level.

1. I do Stronglifts on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday. **Should I do my crossfit workouts on the same days?** From a practical standpoint--job--working out twice a day tends to be hard--because I will try to do strength work in the morning and then crossfit in the afternoon. This seems like the most consistent with the Stronglift principles of alternating rest days with strength days. I can maintain this, but I was not sure it was the correct way to go in terms of overdoing it or exhausting myself.

   I could do crossfit workouts on my rest days. That is possible, but I did not think that lifting weights for crossfit qualifies as the "light-moderate cardio" recommendation for Stronglifts rest days. But this is possible--I just was not sure it was advisable.
2. **Should I use lower weights during my crossfit workouts if I am doing Stronglifts?** So the Stronglifts website notes that you should not be working at like 80% of your 1RM max. I think that was the point of starting with a lower weight--so that you would not get really sore and then have to skip workouts and such. So if I am lifting weights for strength, should I cut back the weight for crossfit--especially if I am doing both on the same day?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If your crossfit gym doesn't have you on a strength program, then ask them for one. If they won't, or they say that just regular workouts are enough, then you've joined a low-quality crossfit gym. Mixing stronglifts with crossfit isn't going to work as soon as you hit weights that are even remotely heavy.

Comment: So at my crossfit box, we actually do like 20-25 minutes of strength training before the actuall metcon workout. During that 20 minutes we usually work on a single strength exercise, like 3-5 sets of bench press or 3-5 sets of back squats, etc. So I tried this, but did not feel like I was really making much strength progress. The Stronglifts work has been a real improvement in consistency in strength improvement.

Comment: How often do you do the same lift in a given strength session at your box? If it's infrequent (e.g. back squats every 2 weeks) then it makes sense that it wouldn't show much progress. I'd ask if they offer a dedicated strength program, either as a separate class or as an alternative to the day's strength move.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Yeah there are a few lifts that we tend to do every week, like a bench press and a deadlift and squats. But generally the trainers mix things up. So we did sumo high bar pulls yesterday, but we might not do those again for a few weeks. I will check with the trainers to see if there are any dedicated strength classes in the planning.